# PowerShell Script to compare 2 CSV files and return row of results

Tags: powershell, compare

Have 2 CSV files with 4 columns in it.  Display Name, WindowsEmailAddress, Department, Title.   I want the script to tell me any differences including if a new users shows up on one sheet or is remove.   Had some success with it telling me something change, but can't get it to output the whole row that changed. So department changes for one user and I want it to output the display name, email address, so I know who it changed for.

Had the most success using this script below. but not outputting correctly.   Any thoughts?

```
$newemp = Import-Csv -Path "C:\temp\departmentlist.csv" -Header department | 
          Select-Object "department"

$ps = Import-Csv -Path "C:\temp\departmentlist2.csv" -Header department | 
      Select-Object "department"

#get list of (imported) CSV properties
$props1 = $newemp | gm -MemberType NoteProperty | select -Expand Name | sort
$props2 = $ps | gm -MemberType NoteProperty | select -Expand Name | sort

#first check that properties match 
#omit this step if you know for sure they will be
if (Compare-Object $props1 $props2) {
    throw "Properties are not the same! [$props1] [$props2]"
} else {
 #pass properties list to Compare-Object
    Compare-Object $newemp $ps -Property $props1
}
```

Comment: add `-PassThru` to the `Compare-Object` call, pipe the output to `Where-Object {$_.SideIndicator -eq '=>'}`. that otta give you the object in the 2nd collection that did not match the 1st collection.

Answer (score 0):

The first problem is because you are specifying `-header department | select-object "department"` on import. If you just run `Import-Csv -Path "C:\temp\departmentlist.csv" -Header department`, you'll see the issue.

The next problem is  that in props1 and props2, you both `gm` and `select -expand Name` which doesn't actually exist in any of the columns you've provided. Change that to `select -expand "Display Name"`, if that is your intention, and get rid of the gm command.

Next, you need to loop through each item in your CSV files, so add a foreach in there - foreach item in the newemp folder, perform the following commands.

I'd also recommend not using "throw" as it actually throws an error and can be difficult to read if there are too many. If this was an app where you want to throw real errors, then that would be fine but for readability, I recommend doing a `write-host` instead.

In the script below I assume that WindowsEmailAddress is the unique identifier for the user. I'm sure this isn't the best way to do this, but it should work.

```
#Import both files
$newemp = Import-Csv -Path "C:\temp\departmentlist.csv" 
$ps = Import-Csv -Path "C:\temp\departmentlist2.csv" 

#Loop through the file
foreach ($emp in $newemp)
{
    #if the unique identifier of email address in the NewEmp folder exists in the PS folder
    if ($emp.WindowsEmailAddress -in $ps.WindowsEmailAddress)
    {
        #find the person in the PS folder and select their properties
        $psemp = $ps | Where-Object {$_.windowsemailaddress -eq $emp.WindowsEmailAddress}

        #If the properties of emp don't match the properties in the PS folder
        if($emp -notmatch $psemp)
        {
            Write-Host "Properties are not the same! [$emp] [$psemp]" -ForegroundColor Red
        }
    }
    else
    {
    Write-host "Employee $emp does not exist in PS file" -ForegroundColor Yellow
    }

}
```